# Plot neural network in r

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

I would like to plot a neural network in R but with inputs vectors containing the weights and the topology. I read this article https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/visualizing-neural-networks-in-r-update/
but when trying to reproduce the below code found at the above site

```
mod.in<-c(13.12,1.49,0.16,-0.11,-0.19,-0.16,0.56,-0.52,0.81)
struct<-c(2,2,1) #two inputs, two hidden, one output 
plot.nnet(mod.in,struct=struct)
```

I get:

> Error in mod.in$n : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

which makes sense since `mod.in` is a vector and `plot.nnet` probably expects a recursive data structure (result of nnet or neuralnet).

Have I missed something? Thank you

Comment: Works fine here: `devtools::source_url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/7471137/raw/466c1474d0a505ff044412703516c34f1a4684a5/nnet_plot_update.r'); mod.in<-c(13.12,1.49,0.16,-0.11,-0.19,-0.16,0.56,-0.52,0.81); struct<-c(2,2,1); plot.nnet(mod.in,struct=struct)
` (reshape_0.8.5, scales_0.3.0).

Comment: After downloading some packages like reshape I saw the plot from the example, but it is not good for more than 3 layers. From the github repository: 

if(length(mod.in) != ((struct[1]*struct[2]+struct[2]*struct[3])+(struct[3]+struct[2])))
      stop('Incorrect length of weight matrix for given network structure')

The struct can only be a 3-length vector.